# Simple regex: how do I say: "it's okay to have an " s " or " es " or " 's " at the end of the word, match those too."?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using Jquery(don't know if that's relevant), here's the regex:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + a_filter + '\\b');
```

So it matches whole words in the variabe a_filter which has a bunch of words in it. Right now it will match 'wrench', but not 'wrenches'. It will match 'chair', but not 'chairs', it will match "john" but not "john's". I've been trying but I can't figure it out.

Can someone please help me adjust my regex above to allow for these at the end of the word?

`s` `es` `'s` are what I want to allow at the end of a word match, so i don't have to include every single possible variation of each word. I think that's all the word endings that there really are that someone would type, if you know more, it would be great to get help, THANKS!

EDIT: here's my jsfiddle, maybe I had `a_filter` mixed up with `filter_tags`, I think i'm doing it backwards, ugh. ???

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/mMTsc/18/

Comment: What does `a_filter` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a group of your endings after the filter concatenation, with `?` to require 0 or 1 match.

```
var a_filter = "wrench";
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + a_filter + '(s|es|\'s)?\\b');

alert( re.test("wrench's") );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qctAG/ *(`alert()` warning. you'll get 4 of them)*

Comment: it works if there's only 1 word in the list, but not if I have more than 1 word. http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/hBdQN/

Comment: @android.nick: Is that the exact scenario, or can the words be separated with a `|` instead of a space? If so, you can do this: `new RegExp('\\b(' + a_filter + ')(s|es|\'s)?\\b');` http://jsfiddle.net/hBdQN/1/

Comment: ...If it must be a space, you could do a `.replace(/\s/g,'|')` on the string.

Comment: This is my jsfiddle, i might be confused and have it backward... http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/mMTsc/18/

Comment: @android.nick: Yes, looking at your jsFiddle, you would need to loop over all of the words in the various `.tags` elements, and concatenate those into the regex as the filter with the possible `s,es,'s` endings to match the possibility of the user input. I'm in the process of updating your fiddle. Be back in a minute.

Comment: @android.nick: Alright, I changed your HTML so that instead of a space between the tags, it uses a `|`. This is convenient so that all the tags can be tested in one regex, since `|` means "or". I removed the entries that don't have tags, because they were confusing me, and I flipped around the test so you're doing `new RegExp('\\b(' + $this.text() + ')(s|es|\'s)?\\b')` and `re.test(a_filter)`. [So here's the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mMTsc/19/)

Comment: thanks so much, that works great. But now if I type `holy`, it will show the LI's that contain that keyword, but it will also show `angels` and `demons` which have zero matched keywords. This only happens the first time I type it in though, if i type `holy`, then delete it, then type it again, it works just fine. Do you know what would be causing this?

Comment: ah, i figured it out. Thanks for the help man, very very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want something that looks like this:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b' + a_filter + '(s|es|\'s)?\\b');
```

Of course, that will not match all plurals (e.g. oxen, geese) and it will match words that don't exist (e.g. sheeps).

Comment: i think i have it backwards in my code, check my question at the bottom for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...assuming you have an array!

```
var a_filter = ["wrench","wrenches","wrench's"];

for(var i=0; i < a_filter.length; i++){
    var re = new RegExp('\^' + a_filter[i] + '\$');
    document.write(re.test("wrench's") + " " + a_filter[i] + "<br />");
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XCARd/2/
Play with the `re.test()` to see it match.